# Page loads before Style and Scripts, causing stutter

Tags: jquery, css, styles, load, refresh

I have an extremely annoying bug and Im at a loss for what to try or where to begin. Im using `Wordpress 3.9.1`.

When you go to my [site](http://www.elevancement.com/) and refresh the page, click on another page, etc, it loses its style for a split second. It's as if the page loads before my style and jquery scripts kick in.

I have disabled all scripts and my background canvas effect, to check if maybe a slow or bulky script was at fault, and could not fix the issue.

Is there possibly a way to tell the page to not show unless all the styles and scripts load? There arent that many scripts and they are extremely light weight.

**EDIT:** Ill post code if requested. I have all my styles and scripts `wp_enqueued`.

Anyone at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this has got to be one of the weirdest solutions to this problem. I left my `enqueue` scripts the same, except I added this line to my header.php

```
// Added Line
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<? bloginfo( '' ); ?>" />
// Unchanged Line
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<? bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Without the added link `<? bloginfo( '' ); ?>` my page stutters horribly on page-load. Can anyone possibly explain why this fixes it.........?

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is another place to put your styles in most wordpress templates. Usually we load styles before loading the page, and load the scripts at last, because users need time to understand the page before click on anything. Wordpress is also designed in this way, loading all the scripts at last, so you should not put your styles with your scripts.